# Why is rustc's suggestion here wrong?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime, trait-objects

I'm trying to implement the following trait, where the `<'baz>` is required for a later `impl<'baz> Baz<'baz> for T where T: OtherTrait`<sup>†</sup>.

```rust
trait Baz<'baz>: Clone {
    fn baz(&'baz mut self);
    
    fn bazzed(&self) -> Self {
        let mut x = self.clone();
        x.baz();
        x
    }
}
```

Rustc understandably fails:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0309]: the parameter type `Self` may not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:6:9
  |
6 |         x.baz();
  |         ^
  |
  = help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `Self: 'baz`...
  = note: ...so that the type `Self` is not borrowed for too long

error[E0309]: the parameter type `Self` may not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:6:11
  |
6 |         x.baz();
  |           ^^^
  |
  = help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `Self: 'baz`...
  = note: ...so that the reference type `&'baz mut Self` does not outlive the data it points at

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0309`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to 2 previous errors
```

So I follow its suggestion:

```rust
trait Baz<'baz>: Clone {
    fn baz(&'baz mut self);
    
    fn bazzed(&self) -> Self 
    where
        Self: 'baz
    {
        let mut x = self.clone();
        x.baz();
        x
    }
}
```

And I don't quite understand what it's not liking now...

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:9:9
   |
1  | trait Baz<'baz>: Clone {
   |           ---- lifetime `'baz` defined here
...
9  |         x.baz();
   |         ^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         argument requires that `x` is borrowed for `'baz`
10 |         x
11 |     }
   |     - `x` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `x` because it is borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:10:9
   |
1  | trait Baz<'baz>: Clone {
   |           ---- lifetime `'baz` defined here
...
9  |         x.baz();
   |         -------
   |         |
   |         borrow of `x` occurs here
   |         argument requires that `x` is borrowed for `'baz`
10 |         x
   |         ^ move out of `x` occurs here

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0505, E0597.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0505`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to 2 previous errors
```

I tried making `Self: 'static` too but that did not help either. What am I missing here?

---

<sup>†</sup> The `<'baz>` I need for another trait, that looks roughly like:

```rust
trait ReturnIteratorMut<'item> {
    type IterType: Iterator<Item = &'item mut Thing>;

    fn iterator<'slf: 'item>(&'slf mut self) -> Self::IterType;
}
```

I want to implement `Baz` for all of these by applying `baz()` to every item in the iterator, so I need `'baz: 'item`. This works fine with just the `baz()` method, it's only the `bazzed()` that it starts to complain at.

Comment: Why does `'baz` exist? When do you use it? "...where the `<'baz>` is required for a later `impl<'baz> Baz<'baz> for T where T: OtherTrait`." Can you explain that in more detail?

Comment: The suggestions made by `rustc` are merely suggestions, and are not always right. You might be trying to write something which is not even possible. Consider explaining the real purpose of that lifetime parameter.

Comment: Updated to include why I need the lifetime parameter. This isn't as much a question of "how can I do this?" as I could work around the `bazzed()` method, but a "why does this happen?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first try to understand what's wrong with this code, without the compiler's help.

`x.baz()` requires `x` to live for `'baz`. Since `'baz` can be any lifetime this means `x` has to live for `'static`. It does not - it is a local variable, and this is an error (you might want HRTB, but you said you want to focus on the compiler errors so I don't deal with the solution).

The compiler's second errors are just that - `x` does not live long enough, or, if we look at the opposite angle, `x` is borrowed for `'static` and so we cannot move it (the compiler shows both errors in order to maximize displayed errors - sometimes it works, sometimes, like in this case, it leads to confusing errors being shown).

The first error(s) is a negligible result of this constraint, but it hides the actual error (for what it's worth, [on nightly they're all shown together](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7e281fcb3ba0685665c5ab4f1be6824a)): `x` needs to live for `'static`, but not just it does not, sometimes it is impossible for any variable of its type to be. Suppose `Self` is `&'some_short_lifetime i32` - it cannot live for `'static`, since it contains a shorter lifetime. This is the reason "`Self` may not live long enough`.